# Testing if value is contained in Pandas Series with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series, for example: `x = pandas.Series([-1,20,"test"])`.

Now I would like to test if -1 is contained in `x` without looping over the whole series. I could transform the whole series to string and then test if `"-1" in x` but sometimes I have -1.0 and sometime -1 and so on, so this is not a good choice.

Is there another possibility to approach this?

Comment: You can use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) function. `x.isin([-1])`  would return a Series of `bool` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this to handle data that appears to be string-like and integer-like.  Pandas Series are all a single datatype.

```
x = pd.Series([-1,20,"test","-1.0"])

print(x)

0      -1
1      20
2    test
3    -1.0
dtype: object

(pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce') == -1).sum()
```

Note: Any value that can cast into a number will return NaN.

Output

```
2
```

If you just want to see if a -1 appears in x then you can use

```
(pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce') == -1).sum() > 0
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
x.isin([-1])
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Or if you want to have a count of how many instances:

```
x.isin([-1]).sum()
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x.isin([-1])
```

Gives me:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

You can refer to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for more info.